# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException when the Element exists on Developer Tools

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to fill a form with Selenium, but I'm getting `Unable to locate element: #PaymentMethod_FullName` when the element clearly exists on Developer Tools on firefox. I already tested for iframe, and there's no iframe.
[image: Firefox Developer Tools]

I'm trying to do:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("PaymentMethod_FullName")).SendKeys(name);
```

but I already tried with the css selector `#PaymentMethod_FullName` and the XPath `//*[@id='PaymentMethod_FullName']`, so I have no idea why it's not working. Also, this error is present for all the inputs on that form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check again for an IFRAME. Have you tried adding a wait?

Comment: In the console window type: `$('#PaymentMethod_FullName')` and press enter. Does it find your item?

Comment: @Aman B No, it doesn't return

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an dynamic element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input.tooltip#PaymentMethod_FullName"))).SendKeys(name);
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@class='tooltip' and @id='PaymentMethod_FullName']"))).SendKeys(name);
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Answer (score 0):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `ElementToBeClickable`.Hope this will work

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
 wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("PaymentMethod_FullName"))).SendKeys(name);
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); 
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Xpath("//fieldset[@class='payment-methods required-form']//ol[@class='form credit label-positioned']//li//input[@id='PaymentMethod_FullName']"))).SendKeys(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It was a iframe, I'm just dumb

Just do `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID OF THE IFRAME HERE")));` and then it will work